# Error creating i386 lxc container on hirsute - does this work?

Tags: apt, dpkg, lxc, container

Attempting to create an i386 LXC Container on my amd64 host using:

`sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n ubuntu32 -- --bindhome $LOGNAME -a i386`

Results in:

```
dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on console-setup-linux | console-setup-freebsd | hurd; however:
  Package console-setup-linux is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-freebsd is not installed.
  Package hurd is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 console-setup-linux
 console-setup
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup-linux:
 console-setup-linux depends on kbd (>= 0.99-12) | console-tools (>= 1:0.2.3-16); however:
  Package kbd is not installed.
  Package console-tools is not installed.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why aren't the base packages resolving the console dependencies properly?